# ¿Como calculo la varianza de un grupo de edades en sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola chicos espero y me puedan ayudar , he tratado de conseguir la varianza de una tabla "usuarios". El campo "Edad" no esta como tal , calculo la edad de cada usuario de la siguiente manera :

```
select trunc(months_between(sysdate,FechaNac)/12) edad
from usuarios
```

ahora trato de pasar eso como argumento de la funcion STDDEV de sql en oracle:

```
select STDDEV(edad),(select trunc(months_between(sysdate,FechaNac)/12) edad
from usuarios)
from usuarios
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error :

```
SQL state 42000: ORA-00904: "EDAD": invalid identifier
```

¿Que podra ser? 
saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tienes 2 problemas.

a) La función [`StdDev`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions159.htm) te devuelve la desviación estándar, no la varianza de una variable. Si quieres obtener la Varianza, utiliza la función [`Variance`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions212.htm#i89144)

B) Utilizas una sintaxis no válida. Tratando de interpretar lo que quieres lograr, diría que es equivalente a esto:

```
with Edades as (
  select trunc(months_between(sysdate, FechaNac) / 12) edad
    from usuarios
)
select Variance(edad) as VarianzaEdad
  from Edades;
/
```

que, si no quieres utilizar un CTE (que en mi opinión es mucho más legible), sería equivalente a esto:

```
select Variance(trunc(months_between(sysdate, FechaNac) / 12)) as VarianzaEdad
  from usuarios
/
```